# Assistance needed with high latency on a home network compared with office network with two connections from the same ISP?

Tags: networking, ping, latency, traceroute

I’m having trouble with my home network’s high latency and would be glad if someone can shed light on what is causing the issue. Could it be because of my router ([Buffalo AirStation Nfiniti](http://www.buffalo-technology.com/en/products/network-devices/routers/airstationtm-nfinititm/?no_cache=1) running [DD-WRT v24SP2-MULTI](http://www.dd-wrt.com) (06/03/12) std)—or my Internet modem ([Huawei HG8240T](http:///products/fixed-access/fttx/ont/hg8240/))?

I have the same network provided with my office network but the ping/traceroute are different. Below is a traceroute from my home Internet:

```
Tracing route to sgp-1.valve.net [103.28.54.1]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     5 ms    20 ms    18 ms  DD-WRT [192.168.11.1]
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4    76 ms   466 ms    11 ms  10.100.128.13
  5    16 ms    15 ms    12 ms  10.100.34.78
  6   914 ms   150 ms   166 ms  10.44.24.226
  7   290 ms   564 ms   512 ms  32590.sgw.equinix.com [202.79.197.176]
  8   321 ms   325 ms   406 ms  sgp-1.valve.net [103.28.54.1]

Trace complete.
```

And this is the traceroute using office network:

```
Tracing route to sgp-1.valve.net [103.28.54.1]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms     4 ms    <1 ms  172.16.4.1
  2     1 ms    <1 ms     2 ms  91.73.172.1
  3    <1 ms     3 ms     4 ms  10.171.0.24
  4     5 ms     4 ms     4 ms  10.100.34.78
  5   114 ms   110 ms   110 ms  10.44.24.226
  6   107 ms   106 ms   107 ms  32590.sgw.equinix.com [202.79.197.176]
  7   110 ms   108 ms   109 ms  sgp-1.valve.net [103.28.54.1]

Trace complete.
```

What could be the reason of this significant difference although under the same network?

Comment: yes completely different connections but the same network provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your home Internet tracroute makes me feel this is a double-NAT issue between your modem and your router:

```
Tracing route to sgp-1.valve.net [103.28.54.1]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     5 ms    20 ms    18 ms  DD-WRT [192.168.11.1]
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4    76 ms   466 ms    11 ms  10.100.128.13
  5    16 ms    15 ms    12 ms  10.100.34.78
  6   914 ms   150 ms   166 ms  10.44.24.226
  7   290 ms   564 ms   512 ms  32590.sgw.equinix.com [202.79.197.176]
  8   321 ms   325 ms   406 ms  sgp-1.valve.net [103.28.54.1]

Trace complete.
```

Look at the 2nd and 3rd hops which appear to timeout. In my experience that only happens when double-NAT-ing happening; meaning the router has a DHCP server and the modem has a DHCP server enabled as well. So they are basically interfering with each other. You *might* get an Internet connection, but it will be “laggy” since the network double-NAT-ed.

While I am not deeply familiar with the [Huawei HG8240T](http://products/fixed-access/fttx/ont/hg8240/) modem, looking [at the PDF of the service manual available here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCUQFjABahUKEwixsbOsm8rHAhWCEz4KHVVzAFI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fenterprise.huawei.com%2Filink%2Fenenterprise%2Fdownload%2FHW_U_149045%26sa%3DU%26ei%3DBBo3U7PFD8K3rAemr4DICA%26ved%3D0CCIQFjAB%26usg%3DAFQjCNEKIYhfPH1P7p5eR86r-0TaQezrxA&ei=AoLfVbGoJ4Kn-AHV5oGQBQ&usg=AFQjCNFGT-9vcXmHkwZMeMR17CXoiB2BOA&sig2=xCKljDhztALxu2cFGBDE4Q) shows some hope. Download that and look at the section titled, “3.3.3 LAN” and read this:

> If the check box corresponding to the LAN port is selected, it
>   indicates that the LAN port works in layer 3 mode, that is, the
>   gateway mode; if the check box corresponding to the LAN port is
>   deselected, it indicates that the LAN port works in layer 2 mode, that
>   is, the bridge mode.

That seems confusing on first read, but I believe this modem allows you to enable/disable bridge/gateway mode on each individual Ethernet LAN port?  If that’s the case, experiment with that.

But when all is said and done, your goal should be to make the [Huawei HG8240T](http://products/fixed-access/fttx/ont/hg8240/) modem as “dumb” as possible. When all is said and done, at the modem should simply behave as a modem and not a router and just then connect it to the Buffalo AirStation Nfiniti running DD-WRT to get DHCP and advanced router features.

Once that is done, fairly confident your traceroute and general network performance should improve.

Answer (score 0):

This problem I raised is solved now after I called my ISP. One of their technical team member look into the issue. The problem was mainly due to wrong configuration on their server side which configured my account into a different plan against to what I was subscribed to.

However, this points out one thing, which means ISP can throttle not only the bandwidth but also the latency of a network. I'm glad this is fixed. Special [thanks to Giacomo1968](https://superuser.com/a/963836/167207) for pointing out the double NAT, since I was not aware about it all the while.